# What is the right way to use Nested states with pytransitions?

Tags: python-3.x, nested, pytransitions

So i've been looking around on the pytransitions github and SO and it seems after 0.8 the way you could use macro-states (or super state with substates in it) has change. I would like to know if it's still possible to create such a machine with pytransition (the blue square is suppose to be a macro-state that has 2 states in it, one of them, the green one, being another macro) :

[image]

Or do I have to follow the workflow suggested here : https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions/issues/332 ?
Thx a lot for any info !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know if it's still possible to create such a machine with pytransition.

The way HSMs are created and managed has changed in 0.8 but you can of course use (deeply) nested states. For a state to have substates, you need to pass the `states` (or `children`) parameter with the state definitions/objects you'd like to nest. Furthermore, you can pass transitions for that particular scope. I am using `HierarchicalGraphMachine` since this allows me to create a graph right away.

```
from transitions.extensions.factory import HierarchicalGraphMachine

states = [
    # create a state named A
    {"name": "A",
     # with the following children
     "states":
        # a state named '1' which will be accessible as 'A_1' 
        ["1", {
        # and a state '2' with its own children ...
            "name": "2",
            #  ... 'a' and 'b'
            "states": ["a", "b"],
            "transitions": [["go", "a", "b"],["go", "b", "a"]],
            # when '2' is entered, 'a' should be entered automatically.
            "initial": "a"
        }],
     # we could also pass [["go", "A_1", "A_2"]] to the machine constructor
     "transitions": [["go", "1", "2"]],
     "initial": "1"
     }]

m = HierarchicalGraphMachine(states=states, initial="A")
m.go()
m.get_graph().draw("foo.png", prog="dot")  # [1]
```

Output of [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIgSx.png):

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, i've go my nested state machine working, but I'm having trouble with the syntax for on_enter_nameOfNestedState. On the github i've found that on_enter/exit_<<state name>> is replaced with on_enter/exit(state_name, callback) but it seems I've been doing it wrong. Could you have a look please ? Here are some screenshots:
https://ibb.co/FnnBckJ
https://ibb.co/vm7NRB0
https://ibb.co/v18689Q